# ethers.utils.formatEther(10000000000, "ether") not working using ether.js

Tags: ether

**CODE : **
const balanceEther = await  ethers.utils.formatEther(10000000000, "ether");

**ISSUE**
I write this line of code nd it shows the error written below ..

**ERROR :**
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'formatEther')

According to me it should have to convert the value of Wei to Ether but its showing the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use formatUnits function for convert

```
const {ethers,formatUnits} =require('ethers');
console.log(formatUnits(1000000000000,"ether"));
```

this can help you for conversion